# How do I move 1 column down to the next row when the browser window is below 990px using CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to learn css grid. I have this code where the third row contains 2 buttons. I want each button to fill up an entire row when the browser window gets below 990px. Here is my current grid-template-areas css:

```css
 .addBasketPopup {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px 125px 60px;
  gap: 2px;
  grid-template-areas: ". head head head head head head head head head head close" 
  "img img prod prod prod prod prod prod price price price price" 
  "buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright";
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
 .addBasketPopup {
   background-color:red;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: 50px 125px 60px 60px;
gap: 2px;
grid-template-areas: ". head head head head head head head head head head close" 
"img img prod prod prod prod prod prod price price price price" 
"buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft buttonleft"
  "buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright buttonright";
 }
}
```

So when below 990px the css grid should change from 3 rows to 4 rows instead. Right now I am using media only max-width 990px and then redefining the grid-template-areas/rows differently here. I am not sure if there is a better way to do this ?
Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/nickbuus/pen/WNZvzMg

Comment: _"So when below 990px the css grid should change from 3 rows to 4 rows instead."_ This already seems to be the case in the codepen you shared... https://codepen.io/nickbuus/pen/WNZvzMg  FWIW, it is better to put an [mcve] in the body of the question, because if you are updating your code on the codepen once it has changed the question on SO loses the initial condition that caused the issue.

Comment: I would recommend you to use `grid-template` and `grid-row` because it is more readable and you can avoid complexity in code

Comment: I was working on trying to solve it myself. But I am not sure if the solution I have added is the best solution - since there is a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: Please include your markup in the question.

Comment: It seems you are trying to emulate Bootstrap by having a grid with 12 columns. I think you are going to tear your hair out if you try to make a CSS grid behave like Bootstrap. Have you read this? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created a grid with a lot of columns I recommend to use `grid-row` and `grid-column` to assign the position of your elements, way easier to read and debug than multiples long strings.
Documentation of how to use these properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).
(Because for example if you want a cell to be on row cells 1 & 2 you need to write `grid-row: 1 \ 3;` *we read from 1 until I met cell 3*)

Maybe reducing the number of columns if possible, or you can nest grid inside grid to handle very specific parts/areas of yours elements.

Except that the use of media query with a re-definition of `grid-template-rows` is the way to go. (by the way no need to rewrite `grid-template-columns` since the value don't change).

Last thing in the codepen link you shared there is a typo, you writed `**@**@media` instead of `@media`.